# Undefined control sequence of bibliography \citep when posting to arxiv

Tags: bibliographies, citing, natbib, arxiv

I have a `.tex` file which works perfectly fine when I run it in my PC using TeXmaker.

It has the following styles and preamble:

```
\documentclass{aa} % Astronomy & Astrophysics journal style

\pdfoutput=1 

\usepackage{epsfig}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{grffile} % FOR EXTENSIONS
\usepackage{floatrow}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{multicol,multirow,booktabs}
\usepackage[caption=false]{subfig}
\usepackage{microtype} % to avoid lines going outside margin

\floatsetup[table]{capposition=top} %caption on top of table
```

For the bibliography, I am using the style:

```
\bibliographystyle{aa} % The Astronomy & Astrophysics style, aa.bst
```

When I upload my files in [arxiv.org](http://arxiv.org) and process it (**tried it both WITH AND WITHOUT THE `aa.bst` file**), I get an error that says:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
l.154 ...of state are dramatically improved \citep
{majumdar}. 
? 
! Emergency stop.
l.154 ...of state are dramatically improved \citep
{majumdar}. 
! ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

The problem seems to be with the usage of `\citep{}`. I don't know why arxiv does not recognise this `natbib` style of citation.

**Do I need to change the bibliography style or do I need to do something else?**

Comment: Not familiar with the `aa` class, but seems to me you answered your own question: `\citep` comes from the `natbib` package, so you need to load that.

Comment: @TorbjørnT.: When I `\usepackage{natbib}` with the current class, it somehow says that there is a package clash!

Comment: @TorbjørnT.: As I have mentioned, `\citep{}` and `\citet{}` as I am using works in my PC with TeXmaker. The same `.tex` file is being complained when I process in arxiv.org

Comment: Yeah, sorry, didn't really catch that part. My naive guess would be that the version of `aa.cls` that you have is different from the one arxiv has. The first hit on google led to a class that does not load `natbib`, so if your version of `aa.cls` does load `natbib`, it's a different one. Edit: Where did you get the class file?

Comment: If the document compiles fine on your local installation but not on arxiv, then this is probably because arxiv uses an old TeX installation. You can try to include the current version of the required packages with your upload. Hope you don't have to upload TeXlive full to make it compile ;-)

Comment: @TorbjørnT.: I got the class file from the main website of [Astronomy & Astrophysics](http://www.aanda.org/author-information/latex-issues/texnical-background-information)

Comment: @gernot: you mean I should include the `aa.bst` with my compilation? If so I already tried that and it still throws the same error.

Comment: Right, that loads `natbib` by default. The `.bst` doesn't define the citation commands, it has nothing to do with the error. Include `aa.cls` in your upload to arxiv.

Comment: @TorbjørnT.: I am not supposed to include `aa.cls` it seems. It is mentioned [in arxiv](https://arxiv.org/help/faq/texlive). And if I do so, I get the error `Citation on page so and so Undefined` for all my citations!! This is driving me crazy!!

Comment: You have to upload the style file that defines `\citep`. You don't show us your complete document, but I guess that somewhere `natbib.sty` is loaded (check the log file). I'd try to upload a recent version of `natbib.sty`.

Comment: @gernot `aa.cls` (as linked to above) loads `natbib`. My guess is that the `aa.cls` on arxiv doesn't do this (the current version of `natbib` is from 2010, and `\citep` predates that, I'm quite sure. arxiv can't be that out of date.) ThePredator: try adding `\usepackage{natbib}` and then upload. It might work, though the document might look different.

Comment: @gernot: As you suggested, I checked my `log` file and I see that `(./natbib.sty
Package: natbib 2007/10/30 8.1 (PWD)` has been loaded. As @TorbjørnT. mentions, it is the 2007 version it seems that is loaded via `aa` style

Comment: @TorbjørnT.: So I should just type `\usepackage{natbib}` in my preamble, and still use `\bibliographystyle{aa}`? Or should I change my `\bibliographystyle{}` to something else?

Comment: Keep the bibliographystyle probably.

Comment: @TorbjørnT.: doesn't work :( According to [THIS PAGE](https://arxiv.org/help/faq/texlive) it is mentioned they use natbib 8.1 or something.. I don't understand this, but I think the error is related somehow

Comment: Define "doesn't work". (I have to say though, that seeing as I've never uploaded anything to arXiv, nor used `aa.cls`, I'm mostly guessing anyway.)

Comment: @TorbjørnT.: I get the same error, `Undefined control sequence \citep`

Comment: When you added `\usepackage{natbib}` before uploading? I find that hard to believe, and I've also run out of suggestions, so I think I'll leave this to someone who's more familiar with the quirks of arxiv.

Comment: @TorbjørnT.: yes, even when I have added `\usepackage{natbib}`. Thanks anyway for your time